# Select sibling not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come across a somewhat silly problem.
Take a look at the following html:

```
<div id="product-container">
    <div id="product-1" class="product">
         <img id="product-img-1" class="product-images">
    </div>

    <div id="product-2" class="product">
         <img id="product-img-2" class="product-images selected">
    </div>

    <div id="product-3" class="product">
         <img id="product-img-3" class="product-images">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is whenever the page loads it sets the first product's image class to 'selected' or whenever you click a product image, it changes the class of that image to 'selected' and removes this same class from the other ones.

I have tested this with the following

```
$("img.product-images").on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

This works, but only when you click an image, this doesn't work when the page is loaded.

To fix this I wrote the following:

```
function updateActiveImg(product = firstProduct()){ // returns first available product (I've tested this and this works as desired)
    // attempt 1, doesn't work: it does add the class to the correct image, but when I click another it just adds the class to that image whithout removing it from its siblings
    $('#product-' + product).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    // attempt 2, doesn't work: this will remove the class from all the cildren, including the one I want selected
    $('#product-' + product).addClass('selected').parent().find('.product-images').removeClass('selected');
    // attempt 3, doesn't work: thought this was the final solution, but don't see why it wouldn't work
    $('#product-' + product).addClass('selected').parent().find('.product-images').not('#product-' + product).removeClass('selected');
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: The main issue is that your `img` elements have no siblings. They have different parents, hence they are not siblings.

Comment: "doesn't work when the page is loaded" - please elaborate on "doesn't work".  Does the click event fire but not find any other `.product-images`?  Click event not fire?

Comment: How are you "load"ing the page / elements?   Are you using ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get its parent sibling and then the element. To make it work initially, trigger click event for the first element.

```
$("img.product-images").on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').parent().siblings().find('.product-images').removeClass('selected');
}).eq(0).click();
```

Comment: I've got this to work with just the on click, but it's when the page loads it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @pranac I misread your answer, tried it out and it works. Thanks.